# Connecting VBS C++ code with SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

ok so i have searched the internet for a solution but i seem to not be getting it.

im running Windows 7, 32-bit OS

i installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012 *with all the tools*.

I created a simple database with a table and some entries.

I currently use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express to design applications. I want to write a really simple application that connects to this database just to see how it works.

By the way this is all done on a one machine(localhost)

here is the c++ code:

```
//not sure if some of these are even needed
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\SDK\\Include\\sqlncli.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //what would i put here? 
}
```

What would be the simplest syntax be for the main function to connect to the SQL server?

I have linked the library file and header file in the project properties like so:

Header file Name: sqlncli.h
Project Properties - configuration properties - C/C++ - Additional Include Directories - **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Include**

Library File Name: sqlncli11.lib
this time under Linker in properties - Additional Include Directories - **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Lib\x86**

Some people mentioned a DLL but i could not find one.

So...

*I installed correct SQL package
*Created a database with a table and values
*included library and header file in C++ code
*configured properties to look for them.

Is this supposed to be this confusing or am i really missing something here?